# $\lim\limits_{} u_n= 0$ and $\lim\limits_{}v_n = 0$ then why $\lim\frac{u_n}{v_n}$ is not defined

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $u_n$ be a function $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $v_n$ be a function $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that :
$v_n, u_n \ne 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and such that : $\lim\limits_{} u_n= \lim\limits_{} v_n = 0$.

I would like to understand intuitively why we can't say that : $\lim\limits_{} \frac{u_n}{v_n} = 1$. I know many counter-example why this doesn't work, but I don't understand that intuitively. I mean is there a nice way to explain why this is false ?

Why when $\lim\limits_{} u_n= \lim\limits_{} v_n = r$, $r \in \mathbb{R}^{*}$ we have : $\lim\limits_{} u_n/v_n = 1$, I don't see why it makes a difference in the assessment when $r = 0$.

Comment: Why aren't the "many counterexamples" convincing?  I mean...take $u_n=\frac 1n$, $v_n=\frac 1{2n}$.  The ratio is constant...

Comment: Does it not suffice to say that, even if both $u_n$ and $v_n$ converge to $0$, one of them can converge *faster* than the other one? (Sorry about imprecision here, but we are not putting a mathematical argument anyways but are working on building up intuition...)

Comment: @user8734617 The problem with this is that I can say the same thing for any $r \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: But then we are moving the onus from trying to understand why we *cannot* say $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{u_n}{v_n}=1$ if $r=0$ to trying to understand why we *can* say $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{u_n}{v_n}=1$ if $r\ne 0$. In other words, maybe first you get yourself acquainted with the fact that for $r=0$ you cannot say anything about the limit, and then, in the next step, you find another argument which helps you see that, for $r\ne 0$ there is a limit after all?

Comment: @Salutsalut1 Consider two cases $\,v_n = u_n / 2\,$ and $\,v_n = 2 u_n\,$: what is $\lim u_n / v_n$ in each case?

Comment: @Salutsalut1 Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim\limits_{} u_n= \lim\limits_{} v_n = 0$$
tells us intuitively, that when $n$ gets larger and larger $v_n,u_n$ are becoming smaller and smaller.

So, when you look at $\lim_n \frac{u_n}{v_n}$ you are really asking:

**What happens if I divide a quantity which becomes smaller and smaller by another quantity which becomes smaller and smaller?**

It should not take too long to convince yourself that the correct answer is **It depends.** It really matters how the two quantities are related.

The question is a (more complicated version of): What do you get if you divide a small number by another small number. Then answer is not 1, it is you could get anything.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that $\frac{r}{r}=1$ is true only for $r\neq 0$ thus you can calculate the limit by algebraic rules. When $v_n$ and $u_n$ tend to 0 you need to consider “how” they tend to 0 and in this case the limit can assume any value or do not exist at all.

Answer (score 0):

For example, let $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $y_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$. Then, $x_n\rightarrow 0$ and $y_n\rightarrow 0$, but 
$$ \frac{x_n}{y_n} =n\rightarrow \infty.$$

Now, let $x_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $y_n=\frac{1}{n}$.  Then, $x_n\rightarrow 0$ and $y_n\rightarrow 0$, but 
$$ \frac{x_n}{y_n} =\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow 0.$$

Then we can to conclude that in this case the limit is undefined.